# How can I show a Threejs Model with gatsby

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gatsby, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to use Gatsby to show a Threejs model.

As Gatsby is based on react, I guess that it is possible to do it

The model is a simple box this time:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "react-three-fiber";
import { BoxBufferGeometry, MeshStandardMaterial } from "three";

const Box = (props) => {
    // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh
    const mesh = useRef();

    // Set up state for the hovered and active state
    const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false);
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

    // Rotate mesh every frame, this is outside of React without overhead
    useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01));

    return (
        <mesh
            {...props}
            ref={mesh}
            scale={active ? [1.5, 1.5, 1.5] : [1, 1, 1]}
            onClick={(e) => setActive(!active)}
            onPointerOver={(e) => setHover(true)}
            onPointerOut={(e) => setHover(false)}
        >
            <BoxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[1, 1, 1]} />
            <MeshStandardMaterial
                attach="material"
                color={hovered ? "hotpink" : "orange"}
            />
        </mesh>
    );
};

const ShowModel = () => (
    <Canvas>
        <ambientLight />
        <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
        <Box position={[-1.2, 0, 0]} />
        <Box position={[1.2, 0, 0]} />
    </Canvas>
);

export default ShowModel;
```

It compiles ok, but when I execute the code, I get this:

[image]

I'm simply putting the component in the pages folder

[image]

And calling it with

```
const IndexPage = () => (
    <div>
        <Link to="/ShowModel">Go to "ShowModel"</Link> <br />
    </div>
);
```

What could I be missing here

Thanks in advance,

Rafael

**EDIT**

I changed the name, from ShowModel to showModel, but the problem still appears.

I think it could be related to the 3D model...

Comment: Where do you export ShowModel.js component ?

Comment: At the end of the file: "export default ShowModel"

Comment: Sorry my bad i meant import

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, Gatsby is a React-based framework hence all the component handling must be React-based too.

That said, `ShowModel.js` should become `showModel.js` (checkout the capitalization) to allow Gatsby to interpret the file as a page and not as a React component.

Further details:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19167
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15759#issuecomment-511557139

Normally this kind of issue (`Element type is invalid: Expected a string`) is related in the way of the component importation/exportation. Double-check if they need to be imported as a default one or not. My concern is about:

```
import { BoxBufferGeometry, MeshStandardMaterial } from "three";
```

Comment: I changed the name, but the error still appears: "One unhandled runtimeerror found in your files. See the list below to fix it:

Error in function createFiberFromTypeAndProps in ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25058
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined"

It's the same error

Comment: Have you tried running `gatsby clean` and retrying the process? All those lowercased components look odd to me (`ambientLight`, `pointLight`, etc). Try commenting on them for now

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Gatsby clean I mean

Comment: I did it. I deleted the line "import { BoxBufferGeometry, MeshStandardMaterial } from "three";", and it worked

Comment: `gatsby clean` runs in the same way you run `gatsby develop` (it might be helpful in the future).

Comment: I'm glad we finally figured it out. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue